# Feeding The Baby After The Next Harvest

Tags: agricola

In Agricola the rules say something like if family growth occurs in the round before a harvest, the baby only needs one food.  Do you think this could be a rules "typo" and they actually meant to say in the "stage" before a harvest?  It would sure make feeding the family easier.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking. Are you saying that, if you have a baby two rounds prior to the harvest (so you have a grown adult in the round just before the harvest), that it should only take one food?

Answer (score 16):

The only time that a family member is only fed 1 food instead of 2 food is if that family member was just added to the family in the round that immediately preceded that harvest. In other words, if that family member has never yet taken any actions.

Comment: Thank you.  I was afraid that's how the game was meant to be played.  I just find feeding the family onerous enough already!  You just always seem to need one more turn to accomplish your goals.  :(